# C++ template container without class/struct?

Tags: c++, templates, containers

Is it possible to have a container which contains different type of values ?
Something like:

```
template<class Value>
std::map<std::string, Value> values;
```

Comment: You can create a container for void*

Comment: From a strict C++ typing point of view, the answer is no. From a practical point of view, there are other options. If you can post what you are trying to accomplish, you might get more useful feedback.

Comment: `std::map<std::string, boost::any>`

Comment: Thanks AK_ and Praetorian I needed something like this. I just realised float* is sufficient in what I am doing. ( container of uniforms (vectors, matrices...) in a Shader class )

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you want to do this, can you clarify it?

You shouldn't mix different object types in a single map. If you do it how are you going to know which type is stored in each cell?

If you want to store some custom classes, it's better to create a parent class and use the map with this parent class and then you can add child classes without any problem.

Comment: If I know that every different type of value that I store in my map has a method like "getFloatArray()" for example, there is no need to know the type, I could simply do "float* value = mymap[string].getFloatArray()" ( that's what I need, float arrays of matrices, vectors etc, but I realised I could simply use float* for the container )

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but if you want to do it right, if all you classes need to have getFloatArray() method, then you should create a base class with this method and create and array with this class. It's a better design and you will avoid future problems.